# Validate array of objects

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I would like to validate an array of objects sent via Postman like that:

```
{
  pit_fee: [
  {
    range: [1,2]
    fee:25
  },
  {
    range: [3,4]
    fee:30
  },
}
```

This is my validation schema using class-validators:

```
export class PitFeeObject {
    @IsNumber({}, { each: true })
    range: number[];

    @IsNumber()
    fee: number;
}

export class CreateConfigSchema {
    @IsArray()
    @ValidateNested({ each: true })
    pit_fee: PitFeeObject[];
}
```

And this is my middleware function that takes the request body as input and validates it:

```
const validationMiddleware = (
    type: any,
    value: string | 'body' | 'query' | 'params' = 'body',
    skipMissingProperties = false,
    whitelist = true,
    forbidNonWhitelisted = true,
): RequestHandler => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        validate(plainToInstance(type, req[value]), { skipMissingProperties, whitelist, forbidNonWhitelisted }).then((errors: ValidationError[]) => {
            if (errors.length > 0) {
                const message = errors.map((error: ValidationError) => Object.values(error.constraints)).join(', ');
                next(new HttpException(400, message));
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    };
};

export default validationMiddleware;
```

The problem is that the `@ValidateNested()` decorator doesn't put `error.constraint` like all other decorators do, but it gives `error.children.children.constraint`.

So I should divide my function with an if statement. If `error.constraint` it catches the constraint else I map error 2 times, find the constraint and catch it. But mapping 2 times is not a good practice as it may be 2 times or 3 or any other number that change as many nested objects I have inside my array.

Comment: Your "array of objects" is missing `]`   (`pit_fee: [` is unmatched.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can recursively traverse the error object to find the constraints, regardless of the nesting level.

**Example**

```
const validationMiddleware = (
    type: any,
    value: string | 'body' | 'query' | 'params' = 'body',
    skipMissingProperties = false,
    whitelist = true,
    forbidNonWhitelisted = true,
): RequestHandler => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        validate(plainToInstance(type, req[value]), { skipMissingProperties, whitelist, forbidNonWhitelisted }).then((errors: ValidationError[]) => {
            if (errors.length > 0) {
                const errorMessages = getErrorMessages(errors);
                next(new HttpException(400, errorMessages.join(', '));
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    };
};

function getErrorMessages(errors: ValidationError[]): string[] {
    const messages: string[] = [];
    for (const error of errors) {
        if (error.constraints) {
            messages.push(...Object.values(error.constraints));
        }
        if (error.children && error.children.length > 0) {
            messages.push(...getErrorMessages(error.children));
        }
    }
    return messages;
}

export default validationMiddleware;
```

Comment: Lovely! Thank you very much